# Can not establish a connection with master on AMAZON EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, ssh, amazon-emr

For the first time, it worked but for the second time it shows me this error:

> Identity cluster.pem not accessible: No such file or directory
>   "Permission denied (publickey)"

when I am trying to use this command:

```
ssh -i ~/meriemCLUSTER.pem hadoop@ec2-34-240-80-35.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Are you sure the .pem file is located within ditectory: `~/` ?

Comment: yes sure at the directory!

Comment: It should ideally be in the SSH folder, but the error indeed says it's missing, so please show us `ls -l ~`

Comment: user@user-X556UQK:~/.ssh$ ls
authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  keypair.pem  known_hosts  known_hosts_old  known_hosts.old  meriemCLUSTER.pem ,It exists in the folder ssh